# VBA Word - Nested IF Function, A Macro Running Other Macros in all Documents in a Folder

Tags: vba, function, if-statement, ms-word

I'm a beginner at coding. So I would like to know how I could use nesting to code a macro (for VBA Word) that runs multiple other macros in all documents in a specified folder. I am trying to employ nesting by having the outer loop open all the documents in a folder (a user will input the location of the folder using InputBox), and within this loop, all the macros will be applied.

So far I know that this is what works perfectly (the code opens all documents in the specified folder);

```
Sub nestingMacro()

    Dim currentFile As String
    Dim location As String
    location = InputBox("Location of folder")
    If Right(location, 1) <> "\" Then location = location + "\"
    currentFile = Dir(location & "*.doc*")
    Do While (currentFile <> "")
        Documents.Open FileName:=location & currentFile
        currentFile = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

I tried adding the following;

```
Sub nestingMacro()

    Dim currentFile As String
    Dim location As String
    location = InputBox("Location of folder")
    If Right(location, 1) <> "\" Then location = location + "\"
    currentFile = Dir(location & "*.doc*")
    Do While (currentFile <> "")
        Documents.Open FileName:=location & currentFile
        currentFile = Dir()

    If currentFile <> "" Then

    'the name of the macros below
    Call findReplaceStyle
    Call countErrorsQuality
    Call saveClose

    End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

Yes, it opens all documents in a folder, however, it runs the macros only on two of the documents then nothing happens to the others. How can I solve this?

Is there a better way to write the function IF, in order to run the macros on all documents using nesting?

Also is there a way to run the macros without actually calling their names?

Thank you!

Comment: We don't understand what you mean by "nesting". Please explain. FWIW I suspect you may be experiencing a race condition - the code opening the files may be executing without waiting for the macros to run/complete on each document. I also don't know exactly what you mean with your last question, but you can (and probably should) leave out the keyword `Call` - VBA doesn't need it. But you do need to use the macro's names.

Comment: What I mean by nesting is when one structure is contained within another - (for VBA) it is when a code has IF-branches and Do-While Loops inside of each other. So... within Do-While, you may have an IF-branch, or within IF you may have a Do-While, or Do-While within Do-while, or IF within IF. Thank you!

Comment: Test this: Put a break-point at the Loop line, so that the code will stop each time it hit's this line. Just press F5 each time. Do things work as you expect, then? If yes, then the various calls aren't finishing before the next document is opened when the macro runs "full speed". To narrow it down, you'd need to comment out code until you find it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need if statement.

```
Sub nestingMacro()

    Dim currentFile As String
    Dim location As String
    location = InputBox("Location of folder")
    If Right(location, 1) <> "\" Then location = location + "\"
    currentFile = Dir(location & "*.doc*")
    Do While (currentFile <> "")
        Documents.Open FileName:=location & currentFile


        Call findReplaceStyle
        Call countErrorsQuality
        Call saveClose

        currentFile = Dir()

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Could not get your exact requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nesting for what you've described so far. If the code is only running on a few files in the folder, that's most likely because you're running the code from a document stored in the same folder and, as soon as it processes itself, it gets closed and that kills the macro. Try something along the lines of the following.

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, strDocNm As String, wdDoc as Document 
strDocNm = ActiveDocument.Fullname
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub 
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc*", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  If strFolder & "\" & strFile <> strDocNm Then
    Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    Call findReplaceStyle
    Call countErrorsQuality
    Call saveClose
  End If
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

A potential problem with your

```
Call findReplaceStyle
Call countErrorsQuality
```

lines is that you're not passing the document you've just opened as a parameter. If anything in those subs changes the activedocument, you could run into problems. It's good coding practice to pass the document you want to process as a parameter, as in:

```
Call findReplaceStyle(wdDoc)
Call countErrorsQuality(wdDoc)
```

Drawing on your previous thread on a related topic, to accept and use such a parameter, the latter sub might be coded along the lines of:

```
Sub countErrorsQuality(wdDoc As Document)
Dim Rng As Range
With wdDoc
  Set Rng = .Range(0, 0)
  If .SpellingErrors.Count > 0 Then
    With Rng
      .Text "REJECTED" & vbCr
      .Font.Size = 14
      .Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
      .Font.Bold = True
    End With
  End If
End With
Set Rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that nothing gets selected. This reduces screen flicker and makes the code run faster.

I likewise suspect you don't need your

```
Call saveClose
```

code and all you really need is:

```
wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=True
```